# Using Collapsibles in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two buttons that reveal two different elements. When I click the first button `FIRST` is shown. When I click the second button `SECOND` is shown but `FIRST` is also visible. What I want to happen is when the second button is clicked `FIRST` should get hidden and `SECOND` should be shown.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#first">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="first" class="collapse">
      FIRST
  </div> 
<br>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#second">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="second" class="collapse">
     SECOND
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `in` class gets added when target gets `collapsed`. So just add a `click event` to your `button` and use `removeClass` on `.collapse` elements and remove the class called `in`. That will do the trick.

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
    $('.collapse').removeClass('in');
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#first">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="first" class="collapse">
      FIRST
  </div> 
<br>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#second">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="second" class="collapse">
     SECOND
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works well

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery use this

```
$('class1').click(function () {
    $('yourDropDowmID').hide();
 }
```

This should hide your previously opened collapsible and to do it for the other class just repeat this but add the corresponding class or id names

Hope this helped :)